# Attribute <something> has already been defined in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I downloaded a project from github. But while importing it I faced some problems.

So one of them is **Attribute "dropDownListViewStyle" has already been defined** error. I searched and found that there may be **two definitions** of the same thing.

But I can not change the file that the variable is in. The error comes from values.xml file. 
The first time I get the error some jar file was decoded but I can not find it again. The gradle of the project is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.com.deneme112"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
```

The parts that dropDownListViewStyle in the values.xml file:

```
... line 9 
<attr format="reference" name="dropDownListViewStyle"/>

....line 117 beginning from 4206th column
<attr format="reference" name="dropDownListViewStyle"/>

...line 829 
<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown</item>

...line 840 
<item name="dropDownListViewStyle">?android:attr/dropDownListViewStyle</item>

...line 1006 
<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown</item>

...line 1017 
<item name="dropDownListViewStyle">?android:attr/dropDownListViewStyle</item>
```

Comment: It will be inside one of your layout files. This happens when you try to give the same attribute a value more than once in a single tag for a view. Please provide your error showing XML files if you want further info...

Comment: xml file is very long and in one line there are lots of characters.